# Let X and Y be two random variables such that the vector (X,Y) is uniformly distributed over the region R = {(x,y)∈ℝ^2 : 0<x<y<1} . Find P(X+Y < 1)

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, random-variables

Im having a hard time beginning because I don't know how to find the distribution function, and thus don't understand how to find the density function. I drew the graph and found the triangle. What do I do from there on?

Comment: A friendly advice: [title is NOT the first sentence of your question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/356647). In particular, see the last bullet: the question post should be comprehensible without the title, even though one should make good use of the title to provide extra info.

Answer (score 1):

> > Let X and Y be two random variables such that the vector (X,Y) is uniformly distributed over the region $R = \{(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2 : 0<x<y<1\}$ . Find P(X+Y < 1)
>
> I'm having a hard time beginning because I don't know how to find the distribution function, and thus don't understand how to find the density function.

If you wish to use it, you should find the probability density function *first*.

You don't strictly need it, but anyway...

> I drew the graph and found the triangle.

Indeed, the region $R$ is a triangle of area $1/2$.  The random points are uniformly distributed over this.

The probability density function is therefore : $f_{X,Y}(x,y) = 2\cdot\mathbf 1_{0<x<y<1}$  $$f_{X,Y}(x,y) = \begin{cases}2&:& 0<x<y<1\\0&:&\textsf{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

> What do I do from there on?

Draw the line $x+y=1$ on your graph.  Notice how it divides the triangle.  The ratio of areas will give the probability.

$$\mathsf P(X+Y<1) =\dfrac{\lvert R\cap\{(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2:x+y<1\}\rvert}{\lvert R \rvert}$$

Or you might do it the long way.  If you really want to:

$$\begin{align}\mathsf P(X+Y\lt 1)&=\int_0^1\int_0^{\min(y,1-y)}2~\mathrm d x~\mathrm d y\\[1ex]&=\int_0^{1/2}\int_0^y 2\mathsf d x\mathsf d y+\int_{1/2}^1\int_0^{1-y} 2\mathsf d x\mathsf d y\\[1ex]&~~\vdots\end{align}$$